# HTML5 how to make table borders even?

Tags: css, html, html-table, border

I've got an assignment from college to do and I've one question.
This is what I am supposed to do:

[image]

And the blue border is even. On my site:
[image]

It is not. Is there any CSS to make them even ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Module Description</th>

       </tr>
       <tr>
       <td>The successful learner will, through the use of a realistic commercial scenario, take a project through the software development lifecycle. They must take their project from problem statement through the significant phases of a software project. </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
            <th>Learning Outcomes</th>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td>On a successful completion of this module the learner will/should be able to do...</td>
       </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes there is CSS to make them even, but without sharing your code, it will be a guessing game.

Comment: @@AdamBuchananSmith I am using very simple html5 I believe. This might be little messy tho. 
`<table> <tr> <th>Module Description</th> </tr> <tr> <td>xxxx. </td> </tr> <tr> <th>Learning Outcomes</th> </tr> <tr> <td>xxx</td> </tr> </table>`

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by even borders. You mean you want all blue header cells to be the same width?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about width="100%" attribute. This was the answer for my question. Sorry for this missleading question :D